# unable to make a package run in nextjs which is working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

[Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsme-react) I am using JSME React npm package for using JSME editor to run on my app. this package is working perfectly fine in reactjs. But not working in nextjs project. can anyone point out where I am doing wrong. Whenever i install in a next js problem and run the app i am getting `JSME initialization error: HTML id jsme11798 not found Error` in console and the editor is not visible.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Jsme } from "jsme-react";

function Editor() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Jsme height="300px" width="400px" options="oldlook,star" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Editor;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the editors need to run on browser, try to import **Editor** component on client side only. [Documentaion](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

In your page file:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Editor= dynamic(
  () => import('../components/Editor'), //Editor component path
  { ssr: false }
)
```